# How to check if startTime is less than endTime in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup

I am getting time in this format like startTime="1:00 am" and endTime="12:00 pm" how can to check if endTime>startTime . I'm using react-timekeeper component

Comment: From where you are getting this value, check plugin you've used or checkout moment or date-fns

Answer (score 0):

simply use the logic if

1. pm is always > am, so if endtime is pm and start time is am, endtime>start-time
2. if both pm or both am, difference the numeric value of time

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create an object of Date class in your program.

```js
var startTime = new Date()
```

In the same way create an object for endTime at place where you need in your program.

```js
var endTime = new Date()
```

Simply subtract startTime from endTime and if difference is +ve then endTime is larger than startTime

```js
var diff = endTime - startTime;
```

Or
You can specifically check it with time.

```js
var diff = endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime();
```

or simply check, endTime > startTime with if and else.

```js
if (endTime.getTime() > startTime.getTime()) {
     console.log(true)
} else {
    console.log(false)
}
```

I believe it will help your query.[image]